# Simple list. Spefics (methods, struct) complie in main-file won't complie in sperate files (h and c). Why?

Tags: c, list, struct, include

I having a beginner problem, but it is quiet puzzling. I am to generate a simple linked list. I know the concept, so have written a standard code for the task. It compiles fine if I include this code at the top of the main file, but I separate them into a own c-File (with a h-File with the struct and methods signatures) and include this, I get several mistakes, all properly going back to the problem, that the struct is suddenly undefined. One of the compile mistakes I get is this:

```
slist.h:10: error: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances
```

Note Line 10 is the end of the struck (line 4 in the fisrt code sample I provide).
Here is my code (as said it complies fine in main.c but it doesn't if it is put in slist.c/h):

```
typedef struct slist{
    struct slist *nextElement;
    int value;
}slist;

/*
* Generate a list element. Used in append, initialize, insertAtIndex and prepend.
*/
slist* generateListElement(int value){
    slist* a=malloc(sizeof(slist));
    if(a==NULL){
        printf("Couldn't list element!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    a->value=value;
    a->nextElement=NULL;
    return a;
}

/*
* Intizialise the list.
*/
slist* initialize(int firstData){
    slist* a=generateListElement(1);
    slist* b=generateListElement(firstData);
    a->nextElement=b;
    return a;
}

/*
* Returns 1 if slist is empty 0 otherwise
*/
int isEmpty(slist* list){
    return !(list->value>0);
}

/*
* print the list to the console
*/
void printList(slist* list){
    if(isEmpty(list)){
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }else{
        int i=1;
        list=list->nextElement;
        while(list->nextElement!=NULL){
            printf("%d: %d\n", i, list->value);
        }
    }
    return;
}

/*
* Append a element to the end of the list 
*/
void append(slist* list,int value){
    slist* z=generateListElement(value);
    while(list->nextElement!=NULL){
        list=list->nextElement;
    }
    list->nextElement=z;
    return;
}

/* 
* Prepend a element to the start of the list
*/
void prepend(slist* list,int value){
    slist* oldFirst=list->nextElement;
    list->value++;
    slist* a=generateListElement(value);
    a->nextElement=oldFirst;
    list->nextElement=a;
    return;
}

/*
* Returns pointer to value of element at given index, 0 if list empty or index out of range
*/
int elementAtIndex(slist* list, int index){
    index=abs(index);
    if(list->value==0 || list->value>=index){
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<index && list->nextElement!=NULL; i++){
        list=list->nextElement;
    }
    return list->value;
}

/*
* Insert element at given index, generate elements with value 0 if needed
*/
void insertAtIndex(slist* list, int index, int value){
    index=abs(index);
    slist* a=generateListElement(value);
    if(list->value>index){
        list->value++;
    }else{
        list->value+=1+(index-list->value);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<index; j++){
        if(list->nextElement==NULL){
            slist* insertElement=generateListElement(0);
            list=insertElement;
        }else{
            list=list->nextElement;
        }
    }
    slist* nextToA=list->nextElement;
    list->nextElement=a;
    a->nextElement=nextToA;
    return; 
}

/*
* Remove Element at given index, returns 1 in case of success 0 otherwise (list empty, index out of range etc.)
*/
int removeElementAtIndex(slist* list,int index){
    index=abs(index);
    if(index>list->value){
        return 0;
    }
    slist* a=list;
    slist* b=list->nextElement;
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
        a=a->nextElement;
        b=b->nextElement;
    }
    slist* c=b;
    b=b->nextElement;
    a->nextElement=b;
    free(c);
    return 1;
}

/*
* Deletes the entire list.
*/
void deleteList(slist* list){
    slist* a=list;
    slist* b=list->nextElement;
    int index=a->value;
    free(a);
    for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
        a=b;
        b=b->nextElement;
        free(a);
    }
    return;
}
```

Just to avoid being lectured about including sperate my files look like this:
slist.h:

```
#ifndef slist
#define slist

/*
* Starting point for slist is the next element the first element counts the elements in the list
*/
typedef struct slist{
    struct slist* nextElement;
    int value;
}slist;

/*
* Generate a list element. Used in append, initialize, insertAtIndex and prepend
*/
slist* generateListElement(int value);

//...

#endif
```

slist.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "slist.h"

/*
* Generate a list element. Used in append, initialize, insertAtIndex and prepend.
*/
slist* generateListElement(int value){
//...
```

and main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stack.h"

int main(void) { //...
```

Comment: Do you know what `#define slist` does?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define slist
```

That tells the preprocessor to replace every occurence of `slist` in the header file with an empty token. Specifically, after preprocessing the typedef becomes:

```
typedef struct {
    struct * nextElement;
    int value;
};
```

It's generally not a good idea to have so many overloaded uses of the same keyword. Would suggest you change the header file to use a different `#define` token for the include guard. A common convention is to use capitialised file name. For example:

```
#ifndef SLIST_H
#define SLIST_H

...

#endif
```